# Object value assigned to odd and even numbers but doesn´t work on `if` statement

Tags: python

I know there is another way to check if an `input` number or value is an even or odd number with the `%`. I just think that doing it this way should work aswell, i came out to the conclusion that something is wrong with the `even` and `uneven` assignment of numbers but i can't seem to find anything online that solves this issue. The program should work in such a way that when you input some number it will recognize the last digit of that number and based on that it will check if its within the `even`and `uneven` values.

```
n = int(input())
turnstr = int(repr(n)[-1])
w = "Weird"
nw = "Not Weird"
even = (0, 2, 4, 6, 8)
uneven = (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
if turnstr == uneven:
    print(w)
if turnstr == even and n == range(2, 5):
    print(nw)
if turnstr == even and n == range(6, 20):
    print(w)
if turnstr == even and n > 20:
    print(nw)
```

Comment: `turnstr` is a number `uneven` is a tuple. They won't ever be `==`. Maybe `if turnstr in uneven:` would be a better test.

Comment: oh, makes sense now, i tried before assigning one value to `even` and it worked but i didnt think of that. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a list for even/odd. `turnstr % 2 == 0` is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching it to this

```
n = int(input())
turnstr = int(repr(n)[-1])
w = "Weird"
nw = "Not Weird"
even = (0, 2, 4, 6, 8)
uneven = (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
if turnstr in uneven:
    print(w)
if turnstr in even and n in range(2, 5):
    print(nw)
if turnstr in even and n in range(6, 20):
    print(w)
if turnstr in even and n > 20:
    print(nw)
```

It would also be cleaner and more efficent to nest your if statements and rip out duplicate logic.

```
n = int(input())
turnstr = int(repr(n)[-1])
w = "Weird"
nw = "Not Weird"
even = (0, 2, 4, 6, 8)
uneven = (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
if turnstr in uneven:
    print(w)
elif turnstr in even:
    if n in range(6, 20):
        print(w)
    else:
        print(nw)
```

Comment: Thankss! Have a good day!

Comment: @Roger99 thanks for the vote.  You can combine this with Adrian's too, so that you don't track the even tuple and don't have to multiple if statements for print(nw)

Answer (score 1):

Replace all your `==` with `in` to check if `turnstr` (an integer) is in the tuple of even/uneven numbers.

More optimised code:

```
n = int(input())
turnstr = int(repr(n)[-1])
w = "Weird"
nw = "Not Weird"
uneven = (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
if turnstr in uneven:
    print(w)
else if n in range(2, 5):
    print(nw)
else if n in range(6, 20):
    print(w)
else if n > 20:
    print(nw)
```

So that the program does not keep having to search through the `even` tuple for the integer when it is implicit it is in it after the first condition (checking if the last digit is odd).

Comment: Thank you so much!. Have a good day.